# Simplify the imaginary part

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Friends,
I want to evaluate this expression

```
Simplify[Im[(20 + 140 I)*Lg + (7 + 140 I)*Ls], {Ls > 0, Lg > 0}]
```

The output I get is `Im[(20 + 140 I) Lg + (7 + 140 I) Ls]` instead of `140*Lg+140*Ls`. Can someone help me please.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ComplexExpand` to tell M all symbols are real

```
    ComplexExpand[Im[(20 + 140 I)*Lg + (7 + 140 I)*Ls], {Ls > 0, Lg > 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See help on `ComplexExpand`. Ps. This question has been asked many times before and is duplicate. Will be closed.